# Using a tuple or some other complex type in a Linq-to-Entities query expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I want to search within a table of customers all of the customers which in each has its name, email address, or phone numbers match all of the query keywords.

... Which is probably easier to understand in code than in English:

```
public IQueryable<Contact> SearchCustomers(string query)
{
    var ws = from w in query.Split()
                where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w)
                select w;

    var q =
        from c in Customers
        where ws.All(w =>
                c.FirstName == w
                || c.LastName == w
                || c.EmailAddress == w
                || c.HomePhone == PhoneNumber.Pack(w)
                || c.CellPhone == PhoneNumber.Pack(w))
        select c;

    return q;
}
```

But I can't call `PhoneNumber.Pack` on the database, so I need to make `w` a format which will store both the raw value of `w` as well as the `Pack`ed value, and I have to do that on the client's side. The problem is that Linq doesn't like having tuples or arrays in the expression arguments, and it doesn't support `String.IndexOf`, so I can't throw two strings in one and then take substrings.

Any other ways to get around this? Or maybe a restatement of the query?

**Edit:** The generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
(etc)
FROM [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE ( NOT ([Extent1].[FirstName] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[LastName] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[EmailAddress] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[HomePhone] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[CellPhone] = N'rei')) OR (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[FirstName] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[LastName] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[EmailAddress] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[HomePhone] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[CellPhone] = N'rei') THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ([Extent1].[FirstName] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[LastName] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[EmailAddress] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[HomePhone] = N'rei' OR [Extent1].[CellPhone] = N'rei')) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL)
))
```

Comment: BTW, how did you get the generated SQL? Profiler?

Comment: http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<Contact> SearchCustomers(string query)
{
    var ws = from w in query.Split()
                where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w)
                select new { Unpacked = w , Packed = PhoneNumber.Pack(w) };

    var q = Customers;
    foreach(var x in ws)
    {
        string ux = x.Unpacked;
        string px = x.Packed;
        q = q.Where(
               c=> 
                c.FirstName == ux
                || c.LastName == ux
                || c.EmailAddress == ux
                || c.HomePhone == px
                || c.CellPhone == px
            );
    }
    return q;
}
```

This will produce the desired result, and temp variable inside foreach will resolve your issue.

Comment: Well, that's a lot easier than I was making it. Thanks! Wish I could split the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a private struct:

```
private struct UnpackedAndPacked
{
    public string Unpacked {get;set;}
    public string Packed {get;set;}
}

var ws = from w in query.Split()
         where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w)
         select new UnpackedAndPacked
                    {
                        Unpacked=w, 
                        Packed=PhoneNumber.Pack(w)
                    };
```

Then change the condition:

```
    where ws.All(w => 
                 c.FirstName == w.Unpacked
                  || c.LastName == w.Unpacked
                  || c.EmailAddress == w.Unpacked
                  || c.HomePhone == w.Packed
                  || c.CellPhone == w.Packed)
    select c;
```

---

I looked into this further, and I think you're not going to get this done as-is. The problem is that, because of the `ws.All`, it wants to create a set of SQL clauses once for each value in the `ws` sequence. It needs that to be a sequence of primitive types, like string.

If you could change your code to have two query parameters, then I think it might work. You'd need one set of parameters for the things that don't need packing, and one for those that do. You would then change this into a LINQ methods chain and do a Union between the two. Example to follow.

---

It worked. My code is below. Note that I used the AdventureWorks2008R2 database, so mine is a bit more complicated than yours - I have a collection of email addresses and of phones to deal with; a match on either of those is accepted:

```
public static IQueryable<Person> SearchCustomers(
    AdventureWorksEntities entities, string nameQuery, string phoneQuery)
{
    var wsu = from w in nameQuery.Split()
        where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w)
        select w;
    var wsp = from w in phoneQuery.Split()
        where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w)
        select Pack(w);
    return
        entities.People.Where(
            c => wsu.All(w => c.FirstName == w || c.LastName == w)).
            Union(
                entities.People.Where(
                    c =>
                    wsp.All(
                        w =>
                        c.PersonPhones.Any(p => p.PhoneNumber == w) ||
                        c.EmailAddresses.Any(a => a.EmailAddress1 == w))));
}
```

Note also that I found [another way to get trace output](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4a17b992-05ca-4e3b-9910-0018e7cc9c8c/):

```
IQueryable<Person> query = SearchCustomers(entities, "w1 w2",
                                           "(602) (408)");
var oc = (ObjectQuery<Person>) query;
Console.WriteLine(oc.ToTraceString());
```

Comment: Bleh, same error: `System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'SearchWord'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`

Comment: @Rei: you know, that kinda makes sense. Ask yourself how you would do this in just plain SQL. Wouldn't you have to pass the word list as a table, even if you didn't have the issue with `Pack`? In fact, does the query work if you compare the phone numbers directly to `w`?

Comment: Yeah, it does make sense, but there must be a query that'll do the same thing. `Pack` just gets rid of non-alphanumeric characters so that the numbers are compared consistently. It's sort of necessary.

Comment: @Rei: but what happens if you remove the packing and just use `w`? Does it work? And I wonder what SQL it generates for that?

Comment: Oh, yeah, it works fine, to the extent that it'll compile, run, and return the right entries so long as I give it a packed phone number. Of course the problem then is that it screws up the other queries.

Comment: @Rei: very odd. So `c.HomePhone == w` works, but `c.HomePhone == w.Packed` does not? What kind of SQL did it generate? You're going to force me to try this myself and see. :-)

Comment: @Rei: thanks, but what does it do with two words? Is it actually building the query by adding a set of clauses for each word in the word list???

Comment: Nope, it just crashes with a `NotSupportedException`. Sorry, I don't think I made that too clear in the question.

Comment: Hmm... that's close, but the problem is that then it selects anything that has matches for all the keywords within first, last and email address, *or* one of the phone numbers. Maybe `Intersect` insteaf of `Union` will help? Will have to try it later.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `query.Where(a).Where(b)` is the same as `query.Where(a & b)`, and qry.All() is essentially taking a range of conditions and chaining together `AND` statements, something like `(word 1 is found) && (word 2 is found) && (word 3 is found)`...

You can use that to do the following (I'm using extension methods, so that I can chain this onto the end of any other `IQueryable<Customer>`).

```
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]
    public static IQueryable<Customer> Search(this IQueryable<Customer> query, string searchTerm)
    {
        string[] queryWords = searchTerm.Split(" ");

        foreach (string w in queryWords) {
            string word = w;
            string packedWord = Pack(word);

            query = query.Where(c => c.FirstName == word || c.LastName == word || c.HomePhone == packedWord || c.CellPhone == packedWord);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Or VB equivalent

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function Search(query As IQueryable(Of Customer), searchTerm As String) As IQueryable(Of Customer)
    Dim queryWords = searchTerm.Split(" ")

    For Each w In queryWords
        Dim word = w
        Dim packedWord = Pack(word)

        query = query.Where(Function(c) c.FirstName = word OrElse
                                c.LastName = word OrElse
                                c.HomePhone = packedWord OrElse
                                c.CellPhone = packedWord)
    Next
    Return query
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into 2 methods:

- SearchCustomer
- SearchCustomerPhoneNumber

In SearchCustomerPhoneNumber you convert the parameter to packed before doing the query.

Since the phone number will not contain letters and the others will, it is possible to check which of the methods should be run. The splitting will actually reduce the load on the database.

Comment: Phone numbers can contain letters, e.g. 1-800-flowers

Comment: Then you would probably have to run both methods each time, spilting would still give you a much simpler program